# How to paste values in a certain text position in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. First sheet contains table with data to copy, the second sheet contains strings inside which i would like to insert copped data. 
The problem is that i don't know how exactly to define 2nd sheet strings a text start/end position, where i would like to paste?

For example:
on a first sheet i have in range A1:A4

```
<Tracciato xmlns="http://">
  <Riquest>
    <Test>
      <Code></Code>
```

Then i take from a second sheet B2 cell a value 293 and insert it between , so i get:

```
<Tracciato xmlns="http://">
  <Riquest>
    <Test>
      <Code>293</Code>
```

The code could be something like:

```
Sub Data()
Sheets("First_sheet").Select

Sheets.("First_sheet").Range("B2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Second_sheet")
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to provide us with some more details.  Maybe a sample of before and after data.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish? (NB: you won't be able to use "copy" and "paste" to do this, but it will be possible with other methods).

Comment: I updated with an example of what i would like to do

Comment: OK. This is not a good way to do this. I would recommend using a proper DOM/HTML library instead of trying to manipulate that data within the confines of a *spreadsheet* worksheet.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know other methods to manage it (with DOM/HTML)

Comment: It's certainly *possible* to do it on a worksheet, but the question for you is: how do you determine *where* (i.e., which cell) will be updated with the copied text?  Explain the logic you would use to do this.

Comment: Well of course you don't, but from the sounds of it, you don't know *this* method, either. So what does it matter? I still think the best tool for the job is DOM but it can potentially be done either way as long as you can define the logic to determine where the values get inserted.

Comment: If each line is in separate rows in range `A1:A4` in First Sheet, then simply replace that text `<Code></Code>` with `"<Code>" & Sheets.("Second_sheet").Range("B4").value & "</Code>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief example:

```
Sub foo()
Dim copyRange as Range
Dim destRange as Range
Dim copyString as String

'Define the cell from which you want to "copy" the text
Set copyRange = Sheets("First_Sheet").Range("B2")

'Define the destination:
Set destRange = Sheets("Second_Sheet").Range("B2")

'Assign the value from a cell to this string variable
copyString = copyRange.Value

'Now insert the text:
destRange.Value = Left(destRange, 6) & copyString & Right(destRange, 7)

End Sub
```

Of course, practically speaking you will most likely need to implement this in some sort of *Loop* structure. YOu may need to use some logic to *determine* where the destination is, if that is not a 1:1 relationship (i.e., B2 on Sheet1 --> B2 on Sheet2, etc.).  You may also need to use some logic to better define the start/end for where to insert. Right now the example code ONLY is for inserting values to a node like `<Code></Code>`.

Comment: + 1 Exactly my thoughts :)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I'm trying to use 'For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1' where i is a row number of a coppied value. But when i try to use i for a second serie of copy- destination range, it returns an Application- defined or object- defined error. What could be the reason?

Comment: If you can revise your question to include the code you're currently using (and let me know which line is causing the error), I can take a look and make some suggestions that might help.